# Assign a page to two parents/links Silverstripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm using Silverstripe to display product items, and sometimes one product item belongs to two different categories/pages. Is it possible to assign a page to two parents? If not is it possible to use a link for the product item and link it to two different categories/pages? That is something like this:

category/page: Breakfast

subpages:
----------------------**bread**

------------------------------------cereal

category/page: Lunch

subpages:
-----------------------**bread**

-------------------------------------pasta

Is it possible to create one page called bread in the admin section of Silverstripe but it will be under two pages (eg breakfast and lunch).

If assigning one page to two parents not possible, can I use a link for page bread to two pages(breakfast and lunch)? How do I go with it? Any tutorials or modules?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have pages with N (1 .. *) parents. However pages have exactly one parent (except for the root page). Take a look at the underlying code: All pages inherit from `sapphire/core/model/SiteTree.php`. In `$extensions` you can see the link to `sapphire/core/model/Hierarchy.php` where you have the `has_one` defined for the parent page. While you could extend SiteTree, the CMS couldn't handle this, so you would also need to rework part of the CMS. I don't think that's what you want.

I think what you are looking for are DataObjects as pages. Take a look at http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-1-keeping-it-simple/ which describes this. You'll need to add `many_many` relationships and everything else you need on your "pages", but you'll have all the flexibility you want.

Feel free to post any follow-up questions.

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks very much for your reply. The tutorial you gave me looks like what I need to do, I'll look into it and see how I go. Thanks for offering answering my further questions, appreciate it. I'm fairly new to SS and Php, so a bit slow but determined to learn. I can't help to notice that you are the author for the new SS book, that is way cool! From your opinion how do you think the differences between your new SS book and The Complete Guide to CMS Development for a beginner? Any advice on some good php's books or tutorials as well? Thanks heaps and have a good weekend:)

Comment: It's hard to provide an unbiased answer to that. IMHO Ingo's book covers more than I do. For example I'm not describing /admin in general but only in combination with custom code, I don't touch on the subject of unit tests,... My pace is probably a little slower, hence I'm explicitly targeting beginners. 90% of my book is based on a live project (b1-bar.at). It's German but you can take a look at it and get a feeling what is covered (besides the code on GitHub: https://github.com/xeraa/silverstripe-book).

Comment: Learning in general: Having a reference is always good (I'd go to Amazon and look for a recent publication with good ratings), but I think trying out something on your own is most important. And take a look at other modules to see how things are done. For example (based on my book) there's a very simple Facebook widget: https://github.com/xeraa/silverstripe-widget_facebookfeed There's little code, but it shoud get you started building stuff on your own...

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks very much for the useful info, I think I will go with your book. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi Xeraa, I followed the tutorials you suggest which is very good, but I run into a sidebar displaying problem. Would you be able to help me on it? here is the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965258/silverstripe-dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-tutorial-sidebar-issue Thanks heaps.