# Silverstripe DataObjects as Pages Part 2 tutorial- sidebar issue

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I've been following [Silverstripe DataObjects as Pages - Part 2: Using Model Admin and URL Segments to create a product catalogue tutorial](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/) on my localhost and running into a sidebar problem.

When I use the same method to create a sidebar as [tutorial one](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-1-keeping-it-simple/), an error message shows on my site [User Error] Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'categorypages' does not exist on 'Product'

This is the code I added to Product.php for sidebar to appear.

```
//Return the Title as a menu title
public function MenuTitle()
{
  return $this->Title;
}
```

//Ensure that the DO shows up in menu (it is needed otherwise sidebar doesn't show when not logged in)

```
function canView()
{
 return $this->CategoryPages()->canView();
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried `$this->Categories()->First()->canView()` ?
reading the comments below it seems to me you're trying to call canView on the list of all of your related CategoryPage objects (ComponentSet)

[EDIT]
as you mentioned in the comments below, you get an error now in the cms calling canView on a non-object. my guess is you haven't attached any Categories yet to some Product, therefore Categories()->First() returns NULL. please try:

```
function canView() {
  //always show this product for users with full administrative rights (see tab 'Security' in CMS
  if(Permission::check('ADMIN')) return true;
  //go and get all categories this product belongs to
  $categories = $this->Categories();
  //are there any categories?
  if($categories->Count() > 0) {
    //get the first category to see wheter it's viewable by the current user
    return $categories->First()->canView();
  } else {
    //product doesn't belong to any categories, so don't render it
    return false;
  }
}
```

i don't really get though why you implemented this canView check. does it really matter wheter a Product is already related to a category? otherwise, just `return true;` in your canView method.

Comment: Hi Schellmax, thanks for your fast response. You can see I'm trying to figure out this SS. I changed the line to $this->Categories->First()->canView() The page works fine now but in the CMS admin, I click on Product then Search (to show all the existing product) It came up a Fatal error: Call to a member function canView() on a non-object Any suggestions on that? Thanks heaps! Sam :)

Comment: then most probably you haven't attached any categories pages yet. i'll add some workaround in my answer above

Comment: Thank you Schellmax, you are a legend! I wish one day my coding skills will be like yours. The reason I implement the canView function is because the sidebar disappears if I log out of the SS admin section without it. I checked every product in admin, they all have one or more categories attached,it doesn't matter if a product is related to a category or not. Would you be able to explain your code above a bit more like what it is doing? Sorry I'm fairly new to SS. According to my purpose and what you said above, I presume I should just use function canView() { return true; } Thanks very much!!

Comment: calling $this->Categories() will return NULL if no categories are attached, that would explain why $this->Categories()->canView yields an error (you can't call the canView method on NULL). strange enough you didn't find any products without categories, but you're good using 'return true'.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use return true, but just out of the interest, would you be able to explain the function above for me like what each line is doing? I'd like to understand and learn it. Thanks heaps for all your help. S:)

Comment: i added some comments to my code above, come back to me in case anything isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks very much Schellmax, I'm just wondering if you could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072191/silverstripe-dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-tutorial-admin-checkbox for me as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but taking a look at the comments you should change `$Category = $this->CategoryPages()->First();` to `$Category = $this->Categories()->First();`

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks very much for your reply. I've seen the comment, the code I'm using is $Category = $this->Categories()->First(); Any other suggestions? Thanks heaps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error would suggest to me that you do not have a has_one relationship on your Product class with the name 'CategoryPages'. The example in the tutorial has the following on the StaffMember class (note the StaffPage relationship):

```
//Relations
static $has_one = array (
    'StaffPage' => 'StaffPage',
    'Photo' => 'Image'
);
```

This is what is referenced in the example canView function ($this->**StaffPage**()):

```
function canView()
{
    return $this->StaffPage()->canView();
}
```

Do you have an equivalent relationship named 'CategoryPages' on your Product? You need to specify the relationship to the parent correctly.

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks very much for your reply, I've defined the relations on Product.php: static $belongs_many_many = array(
'Categories' => 'CategoryPage'); and on CategoryPage.php: static $many_many = array('Products' => 'Product'); You are right that I need to change return $this->CategoryPages()->canView(); to  return $this->Categories()->canView(); to reference it correctly. However now I got another error message: [User Error] Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'canview' does not exist on 'ComponentSet' Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks Shane. Cheers, Sam:)