# Silverstripe DataObjects as Pages Part 2 tutorial - Admin Checkbox

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm using the code from [DataObjects as Pages 2](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/), so you can choose one to many categories for each product you created under Product tab in admin.

My question is how can I show the parental pages'(it is called ProductsList.php) titles for the categories? Please see the image for details [image]

Or here is the explain: Because all my Category pages are under one or more parents, and some Categories pages are repeated on the site eg Toyota and Honda. I'd like the parents page's titles to show eg Sale and Rental under the Category check boxes, so that the admin person know which repeated categories to choose.

Here is some related code for the Categories check boxes field:

```
 //Relate to the category pages
  static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'Categories' => 'CategoryPage'
  );

 //Categories
    $Categories = DataObject::get('CategoryPage');
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Categories", new CheckboxsetField('Categories', 'Categories', $Categories));
```

I'm trying to figure my way through SS, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Sam

**Edit/Update:**

I managed to make Categories tab to show as Parent-Child eg Sale-Toyota, Sale-Honda, Rental-BMW, Rental-Toyota using the code below. However they are all displayed disorderly/randomly. Any suggestions on how to group them properly eg all the Sales are together and all the Rentals are together?

Code: Add below code to CategoryPage.php

```
function CheckboxSummary(){
    return $this->Parent()->Title . ' - ' . $this->Title;
}
```

And add $Categories->map('ID', 'CheckboxSummary') to the option for the checkboxset in Product.php

```
 $Categories = DataObject::get('CategoryPage'); 
 $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Categories", new CheckboxsetField('Categories', 'Categories', $Categories->map('ID', 'CheckboxSummary')));
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could build one checkboxset per 'parent page' (make sure to have the proper URLSegment set):

```
$salePage = DataObject::get_one('Page', "URLSegment = 'sale'");
$Categories = $salePage->Children();
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Categories", new CheckboxsetField('Categories', 'Sale', $Categories));
```

**UPDATE**

concerning the solution using 'CheckboxSummary' you mention in your updated question, the simplest solution is using 'asort()' to sort the array you're feeding to the CheckboxSetField:

```
$Categories = DataObject::get('CategoryPage');
$map = $Categories->map('ID', 'CheckboxSummary');
asort($map);
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Categories", new CheckboxsetField('Categories', 'Categories', $map));
```

for what asort() does, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: Thanks Schellmax. I've tried your code but it came up as an error:"Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'children' does not exist on 'DataObjectSet'" at line 724 of xxx\sapphire\core\Object.php The page I add your code on is in class Product extends DataObject{} in Product.php. How can I fix this pls? Also someone else suggestd to use function CheckboxSummary(){return $this->Parent()->Title . ' - ' . $this->Title;} but I'm not sure how to implement it afterwards. I don't mind if the Category shows like Sale-Toyota, Rental-Toyota if it's easier. Your help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: my fault, sorry. you have to replace DataObject::get by DataObject::get_one - i've updated my code above.

Comment: Thanks S, I tried your new code but it would only show one parent and its children categories (depending on whichever I put the code in the end) eg only show Sale and its children but not all the parents and children. But I managed to display parents-children eg Sale-Toyota, Rental-Toyota, see edit above but all the parents and categories are displayed disorderly, any thought on how to group them? Don't worry if it's gonna be too complicated as I'll just have to live with it. Anyhow thank you very very much for all your help! I really appreciate that you spared your time for me. Thanks again!

Comment: of course you'd have to repeat the above code for every category page - which only works as long as these categories are defined (and not editable by the editor). but i'll try to respond to your sorting problem, i'll update my answer above.

Comment: updated answer with solution for the 'CheckboxSummary' approach

Comment: Hi Schellmax, sorry I was away from my computer for the last three days. What can I say? You are a legend! How do you have so much knowledge on coding?! Thanks very very much for your great help! It works wonderfully. I really really appreciate your time and effect for me. Thanks Schellmax!! Thank you!! :)